# Serving two index.html files from angularJS applications developed independently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, organization

I have a simple problem. I want to use an angularJS application I developed inside of another one. My question is: what is the best way to include it? Should I combine the app.js files and index.html files to load the appropriate resources and routes? Can I combine it by including one module in the other, like with normal dependency injection? Or is there some other, better way to do this?

Let's assume the application has a root express server and a root/app_client angularJS application. There isn't any code to post outside of my whole app, this is more of an organization question.

Comment: Maybe just an `iframe`?

Comment: Can certainly combine them as modules...one master and one as dependency. Assuming the css is compatible and no collisions of component names, routes, template paths etc ideally they should merge fine. That is the beauty of the module dependency system. Also assumes angular version compatibility between the two because it would only be one app then

Comment: I tried doing this like angular.module('mod1', ['mod2']). Got a mod2 is not available error... :-/ I included the app.js of mod2 in my mod1's index.html file, so it should be there.